# Setting Session-Based Permissions via Connected App

Tags: permissions, connected-apps, session, session-id

Here's my use case: We have API-only users who authenticate using the OAuth 2 web server flow and access SF via a ConnectedApp . At the time of auth / refresh, we want to activate a session-based permission set for the user. This provides them the requisite permissions required to perform actions against REST endpoints.

We have a connected app handler class that extends [Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm#apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin). The issue is, when providing implementation for the authorize() and refresh() methods, I try to make a call to `UserInfo.getSessionId()` and `Auth.SessionManagement().getCurrentSession` which return null and throws an exception, respectively.

I can't activate the permissions from the endpoints themselves because then I get the `mixed-DML operations` exception. I realize I could use a normal permission set but I'd prefer session-based.

A copy of the genericized code for my connected app plugin class is below. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class CustomCloudConnectedAppPlugin extends Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin {

    public override Boolean authorize(Id userId, Id connectedAppId, Boolean isAdminApproved, Auth.InvocationContext context) {
        if (!isAdminApproved)
            return false;

        // custom class to encapsulate assignment logic 
        ConnectedAppPermissioner cap = ConnectedAppPermissioner.getAppPermissioner(PhynCloudConnectedAppPlugin.class, userId); 
        cap.assignAppPermissions();

        // sanity check - throws exception
        system.debug(Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession()); 

        return true; 
    }

    public override void refresh(Id userId, Id connectedAppId, Auth.InvocationContext context) {
        // returns null
        system.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your `ConnectedAppPermissioner` class depend on having an active session?

Comment: Only to the extent that a sessionId is required to insert a SessionPermSetActivation record. The instantiation of the class itself doesn't require it.